# Finding the number of lists in a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a function that takes two inputs, both tuples, and checks to ensure they are the same size before continuing. I am having issues in trying to calculate the length of each tuple.

Examples:

```py
tupA = ([1,2,3,4],[11,22,33,44])
tupB = ([1,2],[3,4],[5,6])
tupC = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

When I take the length of each object it returns:

```py
len(tupA) = 2
len(tupB) = 3
len(tupC) = 9
```

Is there an easy way to have the len(tupC) return 1? I found a workaround by adding a comma:

```py
tupD = ([1,2,3,4,5,6],)
len(tupD) = 1
```

But I don't want to force the user to have to add the comma. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That's because `tupC` is not a tuple, it's a list with 9 elements. It's a tuple only when there is a trailing comma.

Comment: are your users adding these lists manually?

Comment: by definition, that tupC is a list. Those parenthesis DO NOT MAKE IT A TUPLE. That's just syntaxis of the python language. EDIT: Not only that, it's on the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to have the comma to make the len work as you expect, as mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

> A tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma.

The only benefit of a tuple would be to make it immutable,
but if you use lists, there is no problem.

```
>>> listA = [[1,2,3,4],[11,22,33,44]]
>>> listB = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> listC = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
>>> len(listA)
2
>>> len(listB)
3
>>> len(listC)
1
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Being immutable does not matter in this case so your answer works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: sure, thing. you just happened to learn about a quirk of the language. good luck

Answer (score 2):

For such data

```
tupA = ([1,2,3,4],[11,22,33,44])
tupB = ([1,2],[3,4],[5,6])
tupC = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

last one is not `tuple`, as you might check

```
print(type(tupC)) #prints <class 'list'>
```

You might check if variable is of given type using `isinstance` function, you could therefore create own function

```
def mylen(x):
    if isinstance(x,list):
        return 1
    else:
        return len(x)
```

Which will give `1` for your `tupC`, `3` for your `tupB` and `2` for your `tupA`.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, `tupC` is not a tuple, it's a list with 9 elements. It's a tuple only when there is a trailing comma.

As a workaround, we can check if it's a list and return results accordingly:

```
def length_(tupl):
    return 1 if isinstance(tupl, list) else len(tupl)
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> tupA = ([1,2,3,4],[11,22,33,44])
>>> tupB = ([1,2],[3,4],[5,6])
>>> tupC = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> length_(tupA)
2
>>> length_(tupB)
3
>>> length_(tupC)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that tupC is actually a list, not a tuple:

```
>>> tupA = ([1,2,3,4],[11,22,33,44])
>>> tupB = ([1,2],[3,4],[5,6])
>>> tupC = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
>>> type(tupA), type(tupB), type(tupC)
(<class 'tuple'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'list'>)
```

If you still insist on keeping things as tuples of lists instead of lists of lists, and don't want to add the comma, you could define your own function to handle this:

```
>>> def newlength(x):
...     if type(x) == list:
...         return 1
...     return len(x)
...
>>> print(newlength(tupA))
2
>>> print(newlength(tupB))
3
>>> print(newlength(tupC))
1
```

EDIT: Kudos to Daweo for beating me to an almost identical answer by a couple of minutes!